# mismatched input '(' expecting <EOF>(line 3, pos 28)

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks

My code looks like this, I do not know why it raising an error, the error is in line 3 after case when, Can anyone help on this? thanks

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN
      (
        CASE
          WHEN
            (
              ltrim(rtrim(status)) = 'CANCELLED' 
              AND ltrim(rtrim(COALESCE(iscancelledwithte, - ))) = '0'
            )
          THEN
            CASE
              WHEN
                (
                  mincancellationdate IS NULL
                )
              THEN
                CASE
                  WHEN
                    (
                      lastupdatedts IS NULL
                    )
                  THEN
                    '9999-12-31' 
                  ELSE
                    lastupdatedts 
                END
                ELSE
                  mincancellationdate 
            END
            ELSE
              CASE
                WHEN
                  (
                    approvedforbillingts IS NULL
                  )
                THEN
                  '9999-12-31' 
                ELSE
                  approvedforbillingts 
              END
        END
      )
       = '9999-12-31' 
    THEN
      status 
    ELSE
      'Closed' 
  END
  AS casestatusname 
FROM
  tblrequesttemp AS tblrequests
```

Comment: Really bad title and not much context. Just wanted to mention my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I've paste your sql request into SQL Syntax Checker (https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/), and it return an error in your `coalesce` function. I believe you forget the quotes around the tiret character.

There is the fixed SQL Request:

```sql
SELECT 
       CASE 
              WHEN ( 
                            CASE 
                                   WHEN (Ltrim(Rtrim(status)) = 'CANCELLED' AND ltrim(rtrim(coalesce(iscancelledwithte, '-'))) = '0') THEN 
                                          CASE 
                                                 WHEN (mincancellationdate IS NULL) THEN 
                                                        CASE 
                                                               WHEN (lastupdatedts IS NULL) THEN '9999-12-31' 
                                                               ELSE lastupdatedts 
                                                        end 
                                                 ELSE mincancellationdate 
                                          end 
                                   ELSE 
                                          CASE 
                                                 WHEN (approvedforbillingts IS NULL) THEN '9999-12-31' 
                                                 ELSE approvedforbillingts 
                                          end 
                            end) = '9999-12-31' THEN status 
              ELSE 'Closed' 
       end
AS casestatusname 
FROM tblrequesttemp AS tblrequests
```

Comment: thanks!!  this is the error i get when i execute the code send me
cannot resolve 'coalesce(tblrequests.`IsCancelledWithTE`, '-')' due to data type mismatch: input to function coalesce should all be the same type, but it's [boolean, string]; line 6 pos 92

ltrim(rtrim(coalesce(iscancelledwithte, '-')))   the column iscancelledwithte is a boolean, how can i make it work?thanks

Comment: What you want to do exactly with the function `coalesce` ? I have difficulties to understand

Comment: the function will do, if that column is null it will substitute by '-'

Comment: You can't replace the value of the boolean column with a '-' character, it's a different type

Comment: Why don't you use `coalesce(tblrequests.IsCancelledWithTE, false)` ? The error message clearly states that all datatypes must have the same type. So, either you remove the coalesce function or you need to use the same datatypes, meaning both string or both bolean, maybe you can also cast to something.

Comment: I removed the coalesce and I am getting this first error

== SQL ==

SELECT   CASE 
                       WHEN (CASE 
----------------------------^^^

can you send me a code without coalesce, I am new to sql.thanks

Comment: Can you paste your full request without the coalesce plz? In hastebin.com or in a snippet

Comment: Start here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/sql/index.html, then deconstruct your query, understand it and see where the error is.

Comment: what's the solution ?

Comment: I am really interested in the final solution as well.

Comment: I have re-written the code like this 

"LTRIM(RTRIM(IsCancelledWithTE,0))='0')"
Instead of
ltrim(rtrim(coalesce(iscancelledwithte, '-'))) = '0')